# Creating vector image using .png in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, selections

I have a project that I am assigned and am unsure how to do it. I'm supposed to redesign a logo by doing a few easy edits to a logo that is already created. I have the old logo in an .ai and a .png file now.

I'm so much more comfortable using Photoshop and I can easily cover up an item that they don't want anymore or change the wording in Photoshop by creating a new layer over what is already there, but I need to be able to enlarge the logo if needed, and I know vectors are the way to go.

If I have the .ai file but it is a flattened layer, is it possible to use a select tool to select different areas of color, like you can in Photoshop? If I use the select tool, it seems to select the whole image which includes blank area around the logo forming a square.

Can I open the file in Photoshop somehow, maybe as a .pdf, and make the easy fixes I need and then re-import it to Illustrator and save it as an .eps file?

What is the best way to make a circle in photoshop with text on it that can be scalable up to a banner size with sharp edges?

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Hi Yvette M, welcome to GD.SE! To answer the Illustrator question about selecting colors. Yes you can, if you want to color only a certain part you can double click on it (if grouped or in clipping mask) or use the direct select tool. If the file in Illustrator is raster, then no you cannot change individual parts of the logo.

Answer (score 2):

You want to edit the Illustrator version in Illustrator.

I'm guessing your "flattened" Illustrator file is just a single layer with all shapes on it.  It it's still perfectly editable in that state.

All the objects are probably grouped. That's why you get a single square box when selected. There's three ways you can edit it:

You can select it and select Object-->Ungroup.

You can double click it and "jump into" the group to edit individual members.

You can use the group selection tool (click hold the white arrow tool and select the one with the plus sign next to it) to select individual shapes.

Note that there could be groups within groups so you may have to ungroup or "jump in" several times.

Once you're able to select individual shapes you can change the color of the fill or stroke with the color palette.

About the circle text.  I assume you're asking about setting type around a circle.

In Illustrator or Photoshop, make the circle with the (circle shape tool) you want the text on, then use the type too to click on the circle's edge.  Type will now flow around the circle.